# 2 separate div containers - links utilizing the same active state in 1 div container as it does in 2nd div container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to make a link in a separate div container open a panel in a completely different div container (which if you click on the second div containers link, the panel also opens and the link itself has an active state) - I got the part down where if I click on a link in the first div container, the panel opens up from the second div container, but am struggling with making that first div containers link activate the active state in the second div container.

If you take a look at the demo, simply click on the {ÑØ§} Members tab, as the other 2 are inactive atm...Once you click on that tab, a panel opens (not the one I am talking about though), now that; that panel is open, look at the very bottom, on the left side in the div container that holds the info title: "Official Roster", there is a link in there that says "rank", if you click on that specific link, the O.F. panel opens up like it should, however, the active state selects them all rather than just the 1 that is selected...I'm getting close, but am seriously stuck and can't seem to figure it out...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Djdzw/2/

I believe it is pure javascript that would be needed, however, it could also be the css as well.  I'll provide what code I have atm below, however - I'll only provide the javascript since posting all the code that is required would simply be too much. If you could simply take a look at the demo above, it might be easier on the eyes.

```
/* ===== The section below is what needs to be edited ===== */
$('.info_box p a').click(function () {
    var a = $('#profile_list a');
    $('#profile_list a').removeClass('active');
    $('#profile_list a').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if understand correct but for active button when click on #profile_list
u just need to write

```
$('#profile_list a').click(function () {
var a = $(this);
$('#profile_list a').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

});

And here for second part

```
$('.info_box p a').click(function () {
var a = $(this).attr("href")
$('#profile_list a').removeClass('active');
$('#profile_list a[href="' + a + '"]' ).addClass('active');
```

});

Comment: I have that listed in my javascript already...That part works perfectly.  It's the section of javascript that starts with `$('.info_box p a').click(function () {...` that's giving me the issue.  If you take a look at the demo I provided, and read the small section above the demo, you will know what I mean...

Comment: Perfect!  That second part is exactly what I was after.  Thank you very much!